# UIScrollView - recognize bounce, expand contentSize instead

Tags: ios, sdk, uiscrollview, infinite

I want to implement a kind of infinite UIScrollView which means the following:

If the user scrolls and the scroll view would bounce at the right or left end, the scroll view should expand itself into this direction instead of bouncing. The additional space would be filled with new data, loaded from a a delegate.

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method and check the scrollView's `contentOffset`. If the offset is close to the edge of the scrollView you increase the `contentSize` of the scrollView. E.g. to expand the scrollView to the right:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width > scrollView.contentSize.width - 30) {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width + 200, scrollView.contentSize.height);
    }
}
```